# Very strange PHP anomaly

Tags: php

### Test 1

```
if((0.011-0.007) >= 0.004){
    echo 'YES!';
}else{
    echo 'NO!'; 
}
```

Output: NO! <--- INCORRECT

### Test 2

```
if((0.004) >= 0.004){
    echo 'YES!';
}else{
    echo 'NO!'; 
}
```

Output: YES!

### Test 3

```
if((0.012-0.008) >= 0.004){
    echo 'YES!';
}else{
    echo 'NO!'; 
}
```

Output: YES!

### Test 4

```
if((0.011-0.008) >= 0.003){
    echo 'YES!';
}else{
    echo 'NO!'; 
}
```

Output: NO! <--- INCORRECT

### Test 5

```
if((0.01-0.007) >= 0.003){
    echo 'YES!';
}else{
    echo 'NO!'; 
}
```

Output: YES!

### Test 6

```
if((0.011-0.007) >= 0.003){
    echo 'YES!';
}else{
    echo 'NO!'; 
}
```

Output: YES!

### Conclusion

Something very strange with the number '0.011'

Comment: This is normal. Float point cannot accurately represent some numbers so they just store the approximation of the value. When you do a lot of operation, the precise start to lose as well.

Comment: You should be `$epsilon = 0.001; if((0.011-0.007-0.004) <= $epsilon)`. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: you need to fixed the length of floating point subtraction value. cause if you start compare a float value with another then its okey but if is it with a floating difference then you need to fixed the difference length. See the [online link](https://3v4l.org/OAAOC)